# Dragging with a customized window

Tags: wpf, styles, draggable

I have a WPF window, without the default windows 'chrome.'

```
<Window x:Class="Genesis.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Genesis (Alpha)" Height="812" Width="917" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Name="Genesis" Closing="Genesis_Closing"
    WindowStyle="None" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" ShowInTaskbar="False" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="#F8F8F8"></Window>
```

Since the default bar used for dragging the window is not there, I can't drag the window. How can I recreate the dragging with a new control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Window.DragMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dragmove.aspx) Method.

From above link:

> Allows a window to be dragged by a mouse with its left button down over an exposed area of the window's client area.

Something like this:

```
private void Genesis_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed )
        this.DragMove();
}
```

Comment: Good Answer..... Also, if you want to drag the form using a "new control", you can add another grid element to your form. Place it where you want, and add the MouseDown code to the new grid rather than to the window of course.